# How to fix issue when using github add, commit and then push?

Tags: github

I initialized a repo in my GitHub. I issued a `git clone` command. I went to the directory in my local computer where I wanted to clone the repo. Then I copied some files in my local drive. Then I did:

```
git add . 
git commit 
git push -u origin master
```

The message appeared:

```
remote: Permission to jasonkid1/testuli.git denied to jpamittan.
fatal: unable to access 
'https://jasonkid1@github.com/jasonkid1/testuli.git/': The requested 
URL returned error: 403
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any https authentication issue, you need to check your credential caching:

```
git config credential.helper
```

That is:

- On Windows, for instance, you would need to open the Windows Credential Manager and check the right password was entered.
- On Mac, you would need to update the OSX keychain.

You might have credentials for *any* github.com URL associated to `jpamittan` (wrong user) instead of `jasonkid1`.

Comment: @user3073339 on what OS were you? Wnidows? Linux? Mac?